# Selecting features with equal values in different fields in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, select-by-attribute, filter

I don't know how to filter the attribute table in QGIS. I have two columns, `"DN"` and `"DN_2"`, both with values from Corine Land Cover (111, 112, 223, etc).

I try to select the rows that have the same value. For example. `"DN"`: 111, and `"DN_2"`: 111, to erase them, and have only values that are different on the same row

[image].

Is there a way to filter this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**filter by expression** with `"DN"="DN_2"` ? depending on the column type (string/integer) you could also try an : `to_int("DN")=to_int("DN_2")`

Comment: `IS LIKE` is another possibility and would omit the `to_int`.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution via using [`regexp_match()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#regexp-match) and [`trim()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#trim).

Since the match has to be checked both ways means the `regexp_match()` has to be applied twice using the conjunction [`AND`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#operators) to achieve the exact match.

```
regexp_match(trim("DN"), trim("DN_2")) AND regexp_match(trim("DN_2"), trim("DN"))
```

`A Λ B` is true only if `A` is True and `B` is True

---

> ```
> regexp_match(input_string, regex)
> ```
>
> Returns true if any part of a string matches the supplied regular
> expression 
> `input_string` the string to test against the regular expression
> `regex` the regular expression to test against

---

> ```
> trim(string)
> ```
>
> Removes all leading and trailing whitespace (spaces,
> tabs, etc) from a string