# QGIS 3.22.16 Bialowieza. Selecting matching value in 2 fields

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, select, values

I am using QGIS 3.22.16, I try to select similar 'null' value in 2 different field. I tried the solutions suggested from one this exchange.
[Selecting features with equal values in different fields in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/319091/selecting-features-with-equal-values-in-different-fields-in-qgis)
None of these solution worked.

[image]

Comment: Please be more precise when saying "none of these solution worked". What exactly have you tried? What did/didn't happen?

Comment: I used the operator "Like" and "=" between the 2 fields. As well as the operator "To_int".

Comment: I even tried the Regexp match and trim functions in the expression box.  No data have been selected in the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `is null`:

```sql
"Tree_Wor1" is null and "Tree Wor_1" is null
```

Comment: Perfect, it worked .